# How to get control's raw value when it is bound to a data source?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I have a control that is bound to a decimal property of the data source (POCO class). I've also set the controls 'Databindings' so that the control is formatted as currency. eg.

```
TextBox1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", this.bindingSource, "Amount", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation, "", "C2"));
```

Through the `DataBindings` I know that the control is bound and to which property of the data source it is bound to.

Is it possible to get the raw value (ie. the value without any formatting) from the control itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the value using `BindingSource`, but I suppose you want to make it more dynamic and independent from `BindingSource`, so you can get the raw value of data source behind the control this way:

```
var binding = this.textBox1.DataBindings[0];
var obj = this.textBox1.BindingContext[binding.DataSource].Current;
var value = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(obj)[binding.BindingMemberInfo.BindingField]
                          .GetValue(obj);
```

This way, the data source type doesn't matter and you can use a `BindingSource`, `DataTable` or `List<T>`.